# Find probability that the marble drawn from jar B is yellow. Given that the marble drawn is yellow, find probability that it was originally from jar A

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

There are two jars with yellow and green marbles. Jar A has $5$ yellow and $8$ green while jar B has $2$ yellow and $6$ green marbles. Two marbles are transferred from jar A to jar B and then one marble is taken from jar B.

a) Find the probability that marble drawn from jar B is yellow.

b) Given that the marble drawn is yellow, find the probability that it was originally from jar A.

I have an okay understanding of Bayes' Theorem and was able to answer part a with some help, but I am completely lost for part b. All I know is that it's P(A|Y)

For part a I set up a tree diagram, and the found the probability of each combination:

YY = (5/13 * 4/12) * 4/10 = .051284

GY = (8/13 * 5/12) * 3/10 = .076923

YG = same as above

GG = (8/13 * 7/12) * 2/10) = 0.071794

P(B|Y) = 0.276924

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: A good starting point in terms of context would be to explain your reasoning for part a).

Comment: I'm new to this website so thank you, I try and take your advice. I'm very lost with Baye's theorem and have only been able to answer problems with help which is why I have so little confidence.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y$ be the event that the marble we draw at the end is yellow

Let $B$ be the event that the marble we draw originated from the second jar.  Similarly define $A$.

$\Pr(Y) =  \Pr(Y\cap A)+\Pr(Y\cap B) = \Pr(Y\mid A)\Pr(A)+\Pr(Y\mid B)\Pr(B)$

$ = \dfrac{5}{13}\cdot\dfrac{2}{10} + \dfrac{2}{8}\cdot\dfrac{8}{10} = \dfrac{18}{65}\approx 0.276923\dots$

Your answer you found for this part was correct, but was unnecessarily complicated.  Each of these terms should be straightforward to calculate.  For instance, $\Pr(Y\mid A)=\dfrac{5}{13}$ because if it was the case that the ball we are looking at originated from the first jar then each of the thirteen marbles from the first jar are equally likely to have been what we drew and five of which were yellow.

---

To complete the second part of the problem, recall Bayes' Theorem:

$\Pr(A\mid Y) = \dfrac{\Pr(Y\mid A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(Y)}$

We already calculated the denominator $\Pr(Y)$ in the previous part and the numerator also already appeared in the first half of the calculation for $\Pr(Y)$.

> $$\dfrac{~~\frac{5}{13}\cdot\frac{2}{10}~~}{~~~\frac{18}{65}~~~} = \dfrac{5}{18}$$

Comment: I'm struggling to see how/why your work for part a) works. If the question only asks for the probability of a marble drawn from jar b, how can we include P(Y and A) when solving for P(Y)? Also, I've been staring at this for a while and cannot figure out where you got the values of P(A) and P(B) from. Is this the probability of choosing any marble from that jar compared to all of the marbles in both of the jars combined? I've only been able to answer these types of problems with a tree diagram so without one, I'm lost sorry.

Comment: @Semiclassical thanks, yes.  It must have been a typo.

Comment: @user1139725 Originally there are eight marbles in the second jar.  After having moved two marbles from the first jar to the second jar, *regardless which are moved* we will have a new total of ten marbles.  Two of those ten marbles originally came from the first jar and eight of those ten marbles originally came from the second jar.  The probability that a marble drawn after this has happened came from the first jar will then be $\Pr(A)=\dfrac{2}{10}$ since two of the ten marbles came from the first jar.  Similarly $\Pr(B)=\dfrac{8}{10}$ since eight of the ten marbles came from the second.

Comment: @user1139725 "*How can we include $\Pr(Y\cap A)$ when solving for $\Pr(Y)$?*"  We always can.  By fundamental principles we always have $\Pr(E)=\Pr(E\cap F)+\Pr(E\cap F^c)$ regardless the events $E$ and $F$.  This is commonly known as "The Law of Total Probability."  Perhaps you misunderstand what I mean by the event $A$.  By event $A$ I mean that the marble I draw from the second jar happened to be one of the ones that was moved there from the first jar as opposed to one of the ones that was there all along and wasn't moved.

Comment: Finally... as for $\Pr(Y\mid A)$, that is just the ratio of yellow marbles from the original composition of the first jar.  Similarly $\Pr(Y\mid B)$ is the ratio of yellow marbles from the original composition of the second jar.